# how to fetch secret key from multiple keyvaults? terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, devops

I am trying to figure this one out and struggling to get it right.
So i have 3 keyvaults, 1 for each region, US, Europe, Asia so i am passing this via data blocks

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "existing" {
  name                = "mykeyvault"
  resource_group_name = "myrg"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "userlist1" {
  name = "secret1" 
  key_vault_id = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id}" 
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "userlist2"{
  name = "secret2" 
  key_vault_id = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id}" 
}


output "secret_value1" {
  value = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.userlist1.value}"
}

output "secret_value2" {
  value = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.userlist2.value}"
}
```

now what am struggling to put together is, if my pipeline is set to run on region = europe, how can i pass the secret value below?

```
module "testmod" {
  source                    = "./test
  password                  = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.**IFREGIONISEUROPETHENPASSTHISSECRET**.value}"
}
```

Comment: Are you applying the config to multiple regions simultaneously? If the root module config is per region, then this would "just work" automatically assuming your secrets structure is identical across regions.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the approach you have planned to use puts your secrets in your statefile, so make sure your statefile is encrypted and well secured.

Because you want to dynamically reference the values, what you want is probably a data structure like an object, rather than a sequence of variables.

Collect your values in an object using locals:

```
locals {
  secret_by_region = {
    "asia" = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.userlist1.value,
    "europe" = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.userlist2.value
  }
}
```

Then reference the value from the local variable:

```
module "testmod" {
  source                    = "./test
  password                  = local.secret_by_region[var.region]
}
```

Comment: Dan Monego - if using locals to pass "asia" = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.userlist1.value, do i pass the resource group names via data "terraform_remote_state" "keyvault" { ?

Comment: lastly the var.region you have assigned "local.secret_by_region[var.region]
}" do i need to specify the regions in the variables.tf file?

Comment: i have another issue, i have 5 keyvaults 1 for each region and those 5 keyvaults have 5 secrets, so does this mean i need to create 5 data "azurerm_key_vault"  then 5  data "azurerm_key_vault_secret"   to fetch the secrets?

Comment: #1 - I don't know what the first question means. 

#2 - Pull in the region however you're doing now - if you don't have a method, variables are a good way to do it. 

#3 - If you're creating the secrets in terraform, don't use data resources - my assumption was that you had manually created secrets to keep the secrets out of checked in code. Consider foreach loops over the list of regions to create multiple secrets.

Comment: i already have the 5 keyvaults with 5 secrets existing in the portal, i just need to reference the secrets in  my module for each keyvault. so i am guessing i need 5 data blocks with another 5 data blocks for secrets?

Comment: You likely just need to reference the secret if you're pulling it in as a data value.